# React-select V2 - how to replicate onValueClick functionality from v1?

Tags: react-select

V2 of React-select removes the `onValueClick` functionality, and does not document a replacement. I need to recreate this functionality to be able to upgrade.

I've attempted overriding the `MultiValueLabel` component, but it [only receives `className` and `children`](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/v2/src/components/MultiValue.js#L114), so that's useless.

onClick handlers added directly to the `MultiValue` component do not fire. It's not clear why this is, and I'm doubtful it would solve my problem.

Has anyone successfully replicated this feature in v2?

Answer (score 1):

This ended up not being possible, so I [added the functionality myself and wrote a PR](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/pull/2806).